# Formula to check 2 Excel 2010 data columns on Win 7 PC

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have 2 adjacent Excel sheet columns that contain numbers and I can insert an "IF" formula in a 3rd column to check for a certain condition without any problem but when I try to combine checking for more than 1 condition it wont work anymore. I have checked all over the web but can't seem to find a solution to checking for different criteria in the same cells that combines IF AND OR.  What I want to check is if the numbers in col A and Col B are both less than 2.5 then "1" is displayed in the 3rd col.  If they aren't then "0". I also want to check if the numbers in A and B are both greater than 2.5 then "1" is displayed in the 3rd col. If not then "0". Basically, if the numbers in A and B are both <2.5 or if the numbers in A and B are both >2.5 then "1". If not then "0". Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Just so we're clear: if either or both of the A and B numbers are **equal to** 2.5, you want the third column to be 0?

Comment: Apologies for delay. Been out of house. Yes, I am okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

**=IF(OR(AND(A1<2.5,B1<2.5),AND(A1>2.5,B1>2.5)),1,0)**

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I needed. I was using the OR in the wrong part of the formula when I tried to combine them. Extremely grateful for your help.